# Target dependencies vs. Link binary with libraries

Tags: xcode

I don't understand the difference between these Xcode features.

I'm building and app - but the functionality of the app is being abstracted into libraries (so they can be distributed separately as an "SDK").

So I have a workspace of library projects and the app project. I can add library projects to the app project by doing "link binary with libraries". This gives me a list of `.a` library projects in the current workspace which I can link to.

I can also add frameworks here.

In the "target dependencies" bit all I can add is other targets in the current project.

What I really want to do is both - I want my app project to build all the other library projects when I build it. I also want to make it verbose what libraries the app (and other libraries) **depend** on.

So can somebody please explain the difference, and whether what I am doing is the right way to go about it?

Many thanks!

Comment: I never figured it out, however - If you have separate projects in the same workspace and your app uses the lib files then it will automatically build every time. I've had some problems with it not building from scratch each time, but I get round it by cleaning then building if I change anything in the library projects.

Comment: This suggests that you need both. http://www.xs-labs.com/en/archives/articles/xcode-static-libraries. Seems redundant though. If you're linking to a binary then surely that implies that its dependent upon it?

Comment: For anyone visiting this question, here is an [awesome blog](https://dnbespalov.com/2019/02/17/xcode-target-dependencies.html).

Comment: Another useful resource is WWDC 18's [Behind the Scenes of the Xcode Build Process](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/415/), which is quite an advanced video.

Answer (score 10):

It says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-SW1)...

> 2. Drag your framework product (located in the Products folder) to the existing Link Binary With Libraries build phase of your application
>    target. This causes the application to link against your framework.

And...

> 8. In the General tab of the inspector window, add your framework as a dependency for the application. Adding this dependency causes Xcode to
>    build the framework target before building the application target.
>
> The build dependency you establish in the application target causes
> the framework to be built before the application. This is important
> because it guarantees that a built version of your framework will be
> available to link against and to embed in the application. Because of
> this dependency, you can set the active target of your Xcode project
> to your application and leave it there.

So it seems that you're supposed to use both. Seems redundant though, because if you're linking to a framework then its a dependency. I suppose you might want to only link to a library and not build it first. Although Xcode seems to build linked libraries even without them being added to the dependency section. Perhaps that's a result of the "Find Implicit Dependencies" option in a scheme's build settings.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar and was explicitly setting the 'header search path' and 'library search path' in the final executable target.  However this all depended on where the objects were being generated.  Initially I had set this to be within the source tree (actually a sibling directory called `build`), however after changing the location of the Xcode `DerivedData` directory and telling it to build into that directory, the projects no longer built.

The final solution was simply to remove the explicit setting of the 'header/library search path' and set the target dependencies correctly.  This resulted in the project building for debugging and archiving without issue.